# Quick xsl help: ordering a table by price

Tags: xml, xslt

in xsl what code do you type to make the data in ascending or descending order?

I'm making an xml document for music that shows the title, genre and price. I wanted to show the data in ascending order by price.

How can I do it? I don't have a clue

Just so yo know the data is in a table

Answer (score 1):

use [xsl:sort](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp) when selecting the input data.

```
<xsl:for-each select="album">
  <xsl:sort select="price" order="ascending"/>
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [`xsl:sort`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting) inside `xsl:apply-templates` or `xsl:for-each`.